# Can I have a bond formed for only one spin?

Tags: solid-state-physics, spin, siesta, nanostructures, electron-density

I'm making a topological analysis of a nanotube interacting with some metals.

The steps for the calculations were:

- Optimizing the geometry (I am using [SIESTA](https://siesta-project.org/siesta/) code).
- Obtain the electronic density for the final relaxed structure (in cube format with the help of DENCHAR utility that is part of the SIESTA distribution): density files for total electron density (RHO), spin up electron density (RHO.UP) and spin down electron density (RHO.DOWN).
- Run topological analysis with [CRITIC2](https://aoterodelaroza.github.io/critic2/)<sup>1,2</sup> software.

For the three metals under study, I got a bond critical point from the RHO file.
When analyzing the RHO.UP and RHO.DOWN files, for two metals I got two critical points (one for each spin). But for one metal, I only got one bond critical point.

As the recommended way to run topological studies is using the wavefunction directly instead the electron density, I run the topological analysis from density files with different grid size.

The question: **Can I have a bond formed for only one spin?**

<sup>1</sup> A.Otero-de-la-Roza, M.A.Blanco, A. Martín Pendás, Víctor Luaña. *Critic: a new program for the topological analysis of solid-state electron densities*, Computer Physics Communications
Volume 180, Issue 1, January 2009, Pages 157-166. DOI: [10.1016/j.cpc.2008.07.018](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2008.07.018)

<sup>2</sup> A.Otero-de-la-Roza, Erin R.Johnson, Víctor Luaña, *Critic2: A program for real-space analysis of quantum chemical interactions in solids*, Computer Physics Communications
Volume 185, Issue 3, March 2014, Pages 1007-1018. DOI:[10.1016/j.cpc.2013.10.026](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2013.10.026)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, see e.g. the hydrogen molecule cation.

Comment: Can you share any reference about? Thanks.

Comment: Reference for what?

Comment: @Camps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydrogen_cation

Comment: So yeah, this is a paper from 1927.
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01504875

Comment: SusiLehtola and @wzkchem5, thanks for sharing. But in that case, there is only one electron to share. In the example above, there are two electrons from metal to share.

Comment: @Camps Sorry I didn't read your question carefully.  The absence of bond critical point does not mean a complete absence of bonding. Suppose you have a three-membered ring ABC, so that A-B, B-C and A-C are all bonded. Now you increase the ABC angle until it reaches 180 degrees. At ABC=180 degrees, there is certainly no bond critical point between A and C. So there must be an angle at which the bond critical point disappears abruptly. But you cannot say the A-C bonding suddenly disappears at that angle. There is no qualitative change of electronic structure at that point.